# Does hyper client not accept self-signed certificates?

Tags: rust, hyper

I have a web server built using `hyper` and `tokio-rustls`. When using the self-signed certificate, I have confirmed that the https request is successfully processed by a web browser such as Chrome.

However, when I try to make a `hyper` client for the test and try to make a request, the following error is output.

```
hyper::Error(Connect, Custom { kind: Other, error: Custom { kind: InvalidData, error: InvalidCertificateData("invalid peer certificate: UnknownIssuer") } })', tests/server.rs:80:42
```

Even when I check with curl request for self signed certificate, I am getting 200 response.
Don't clients using `hyper-rustls` accept self-signed certificates? Or is there a reason the browser and test client show different results?

Is there a separate option not to check the server's certificate on the client (insecure)?

I used `hyper_rustls` to make https requests.

```
let url = ("https://localhost:5582").parse().unwrap();
let https = hyper_rustls::HttpsConnectorBuilder::new()
    .with_native_roots()
    .https_only()
    .enable_http1()
    .build();

let client: Client<_, hyper::Body> = Client::builder().build(https);

let response = client.get(url).await.unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All environments should reject the self-signed certificate *until explicitly instructed to accept it.* For example, with `curl` you can use `-k` or `--insecure` to tell curl not to validate the certificate. Likewise, your browser displayed a scary "certificate error" page that you bypassed, instructing the browser to accept the certificate.

If an environment doesn't reject such certificates by default, it is susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks, which would be a security vulnerability.

You can disable certificate verification by adding an invocation of [`.with_tls_config()`](https://docs.rs/hyper-rustls/latest/hyper_rustls/struct.HttpsConnectorBuilder.html#method.with_tls_config) when building your hyper_rustls connector.  You need to access the [dangerous](https://docs.rs/rustls/0.20.2/rustls/client/struct.ClientConfig.html#method.dangerous) part of the `ClientConfig` and set the [certificate verifier](https://docs.rs/rustls/0.20.2/rustls/client/trait.ServerCertVerifier.html) to a one that performs no checks at all.

Alternatively, you can install the certificate as a trusted host certificate in your system's certificate store, which is probably both simpler and safer.

Answer (score 4):

To build on the [answer by cdhowie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72847362/2441655), here is a more complete example:

```rust
use std::{sync::Arc, fs::File, io::Read};

use anyhow::Error;
use hyper::client::HttpConnector;
use hyper_rustls::HttpsConnector;
use rustls::ClientConfig;

// customization for "hyper" requests
pub fn get_hyper_client_with_k8s_certs() -> Result<hyper::Client<HttpsConnector<HttpConnector>>, Error> {
    let https = hyper_rustls::HttpsConnectorBuilder::new()
        .with_tls_config(get_rustls_config_dangerous()?)
        .https_only()
        .enable_http1()
        .build();

    let client: hyper::Client<_, hyper::Body> = hyper::Client::builder().build(https);
    Ok(client)
}

// customization for "reqwest" requests
pub fn get_reqwest_client_with_k8s_certs() -> Result<reqwest::Client, Error> {
    Ok(reqwest::ClientBuilder::new()
        // this completely disables cert-verification
        .danger_accept_invalid_certs(true)
        .build()?)
}

pub fn get_rustls_config_dangerous() -> Result<ClientConfig, Error> {
    let mut store = rustls::RootCertStore::empty();

    let mut config = ClientConfig::builder()
        .with_safe_defaults()
        .with_root_certificates(store)
        .with_no_client_auth();

    // this completely disables cert-verification
    let mut dangerous_config = ClientConfig::dangerous(&mut config);
    dangerous_config.set_certificate_verifier(Arc::new(NoCertificateVerification {}));

    Ok(config)
}
pub struct NoCertificateVerification {}
impl rustls::client::ServerCertVerifier for NoCertificateVerification {
    fn verify_server_cert(
        &self,
        _end_entity: &rustls::Certificate,
        _intermediates: &[rustls::Certificate],
        _server_name: &rustls::ServerName,
        _scts: &mut dyn Iterator<Item = &[u8]>,
        _ocsp: &[u8],
        _now: std::time::SystemTime,
    ) -> Result<rustls::client::ServerCertVerified, rustls::Error> {
        Ok(rustls::client::ServerCertVerified::assertion())
    }
    // NOTE: This needs extending for newer versions of rustls.
}
```

If instead you just want to add a custom certificate, use something like this:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;
use rustls::{pki_types::CertificateDer, ClientConfig, RootCertStore};

pub fn get_hyper_client_with_custom_certs<B: Body + Send>() -> Result<Client<HttpsConnector<HttpConnector>, B>, Error> where <B as Body>::Data: Send {
    let https = hyper_rustls::HttpsConnectorBuilder::new()
        //.with_native_roots()
        .with_tls_config(get_rustls_config_that_accepts_custom_certs()?)
        .https_only()
        .enable_http1()
        .build();
    Ok(Client::builder(TokioExecutor::new()).build(https))
}

pub fn get_reqwest_client_with_custom_certs() -> Result<reqwest::Client, Error> {
    let mut builder = reqwest::ClientBuilder::new();
    for cert in get_custom_certs()? {
        let reqwest_cert = reqwest::Certificate::from_der(&cert)?;
        builder = builder.add_root_certificate(reqwest_cert);
    }
    Ok(builder.build()?)
}

pub fn get_custom_certs() -> Vec<CertificateDer<'static>> {
    let cert_file = File::open("ca-certificate.crt").unwrap();
    let cert_file_reader = &mut std::io::BufReader::new(cert_file);
    let certs: Vec<CertificateDer> = rustls_pemfile::certs(cert_file_reader).try_collect()
        .expect("Failed to parse a certificate from the certificate file.");
    assert!(certs.len() > 0, "No certificates were found in the certificate file.");
    certs
}
pub fn get_rustls_config_that_accepts_custom_certs() -> ClientConfig {
    let mut store = rustls::RootCertStore::empty();
    for cert in certs {
        store.add(cert).unwrap();
    }
    ClientConfig::builder()
        .with_root_certificates(store)
        .with_no_client_auth()
}
```